# Eloquent relationship - whereNotNull does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship in Eloquent that I'm trying to query.

```
$deliveryOverride = $product->days->whereNotNull('margin')
->where('price_id', $order['price_id'])
->where('product_id', $product->id)
->where('sale_at', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day)))
->first();
```

I keep getting the the error

> Method whereNotNull does not exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a relation property directly on an Eloquent object, the query is executed and a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) is returned. There is no `WhereNotNull` function on collections.

If you want to query the relation using that function, you will have to call the relation function directly. This will also be better for performance as the query will happen on the database.

```
$deliveryOverride = $product->days()  // Call relation function here
    ->whereNotNull('margin')
    ->where('price_id', $order['price_id'])
    ->where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->where('sale_at', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day)))
    ->first();
```

More information about this can be found in the documentation right here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations